# Magento 2: Flatrate shipping price is not updating

Tags: magento2, checkout, price, shipping-methods, flat

In the first checkout step, where we are providing shipping address I'm updating flatrate price according to the zip code given. The updated price is saving to core_config_data table as usual.But when I take the payment step of checkout process flatrate shipping rate is still showing 0.00 in the order summary block. How can I solve this? Please refer the snapshot below

[image: flatrate not updating]

My flatrate admin area settings

[image: flatrate admin]

Comment: Did you flush the cache ?

Comment: @FranckGarnier Yes. I cleared the cache.. and tried by adding products to cart.

Comment: Did you setup the flatrate for the given store ? Can you share your settings ?

Comment: @FranckGarnier U mean admin area settings? shipping methods?

Comment: Yes sure, and your FO shipping address used.

Comment: @FranckGarnier I updated the question. Please check. What u meant by FO shipping address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54564/discussion-between-sree-and-franck-garnier).

Comment: You should give this extension a try https://magecomp.com/magento-2-multiple-flat-rate-shipping.html

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g0x0c0    
http://prntscr.com/g0x17b

Comment: Find the screenshots we are also facing shipping methods pricing issue

Comment: @sreelakshmi, Any solution here? I'm also facing the same kind of problem.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the current product in cart and customer logout once. Do flush cache and check the result.

This will fix your issue.